# Mixed content error in Network profile - activity tab

Tags: bug, status-completed, api, network-profile, ssl

In the [network profile activity tab](https://stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=activity), when trying to expand the answered or asked posts, we are getting the following mixed content error:

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://stackexchange.com/users/2855348/arulkumar?tab=activity' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://api.stackexchange.com/2.0/questions/297176?site=meta.stackexchange.com&filter=....'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

[image: Mixed content error]

It is still using the `http://` API calls, that caused the issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like this was missed in the move to HTTPS.

Fixed now - API calls on that page now go via HTTPS.

Thanks for reporting.